# While-Loop with x in [] clause giving me syntax error. I don't know what im doing wrong

Tags: python, list, while-loop, append, syntax-error

This program is supposed to get float numbers as an input and give the total sum of the given inputs in the end. You can end the program by adding '0' as input. I tried using a the following while-loop, but its giving me a syntax error all the time. You can tell me what im doing wrong?

```
x = []
x.append(float(input("Fließkommazahl eingeben")))
while 0 not in x:
    x.append(float(input("Zahl eingeben")
print(sum(x))
```

Edit:I made some changes, such as unindenting the print command and adding an '(', and now its giving me a syntax error at line 6.

Comment: You're missing a `)` at the end of `x.append(float(input("Fließkommazahl eingeben"))`.

Comment: `while-else` does not do what you think it does. It might work here, but more by accident. Just remove the `else` and unindent the print.

Comment: you're also missing a two `)` in the second append

Comment: Im so effing stupid, thank you. I was already questioning everything i learned about python. I think i should not instantly go into a deep think without checking the basics..